# PHP: confused about file permissions, cannot unlink setup file?

Tags: php, file, permissions, path, chmod

I created a `setup.php` to handle MySQL table generation, and as an obvious precaution I added a way to delete it after it was finished. As using `unlink(__FILE__)` is impossible to do, I added deletion code to `main.php?action=deleteconfig` to unlink the file.

`setup.php` has permissions `777`, but it gives me a permission denied error when I unlink it.. My directory is `drwxr-xr-x` and my `main.php` is `-rw-r--r--`.

Would I need to set `main.php` to 777 as well before it can delete `setup.php` ? I am confused about file permissions here and why they do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user running php needs to have write permissions for the directory in order to modify its contents (ie. delete/create). so you could `chown` the directory to the php user, or add the php user to the group and chmod the directory to so that the group ha `w` permissions.

Comment: UH OH, I did `system('whoami');` and it said "nobody nobody", would I need to chown the file to nobody for this to work? Or is `nobody` no one .. a default?

Comment: `nobody` can have special connotations depending on what youre running. What OS is it?

Comment: @john: sorry i haven 0 exp. with Arch. But i find it odd they run Apache as `nobody`. Typically on the flavors of linux i use its set up by default as something like `www` or `www-data`.

Comment: I'm releasing the software to other people to use (online), so maybe I can warn them to ensure it's owned by the same user as httpd and it should be a problem, I'll try and dig up what I can about `nobody` in the time being. Thanks for the insight that you could provide!

Comment: Well generally speaking a hosting account is not going to run as `nobody` they are going to have a specific user and group that it runs as to facilitate other things.

Comment: I'll accept, because it answers quite a few of my other questions I had in my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently run into a similar problem, in a setup where uploaded files are owned by nobody/nobody.

For the unlink to work correctly, make sure you are using the path to the file you want to delete, not the url